# Border around blank data in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm currently creating a report in Crystal Reports and each item has a border. The problem is that some of the fields can have a NULL value. When a field has a value of NULL the border doesn't show up, leaving an unsightly gap in the data.

The only solution I was able to come up with is that I create a formula for each column that displays the value if it's not null or displays a blank space when it's not null to trick crystal into thinking there is a value. This would be a major pain and definitely be confusing to anyone trying to modify the report. Is there a better solution to this problem that I might have missed?

Note: I'm unable to modify the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the report options to give the default value to the null fields. But it may be not desirable for other cases.

If you wanna try it, right click the report and select "report options". Check the options "convert database null values to default" and/or "convert other null values to default".

Comment: I checked and both of these boxes are checked, but I am still getting no boarders on elements with no values.

Comment: what is the type of the column?

Comment: The column I was looking at was a number.

Comment: are you using a dataset or binding directly do the database? if you are using a dataset, you may try to set the default value on the data column.

Comment: I'm getting the data from a view; but i'm unable to modify the sql of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a textbox on the report, then place the field inside that textbox. The borders would be placed on the textbox and would always appear regardless of the field value.

A few drawbacks to this,

- Formatting cannot be done on the field any more (e.g. if you needed to display 123 as $123.00 you'd need to create a formula to perform the formatting then insert that formula into the textbox)
- Export the data to Excel would not respect the data type - any numbers would come over formatted as text (though displayed exactly as you formatted them on the report) with that little green arrow in the cell

I found that method from https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/9923668#9923668